# How to change chromiums windows buttons to gnome defaults?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, themes, chromium, window-manager

Chromium's custom Minimise/Maximise/Close buttons do not fit in with my Gnome 3 theme. I have managed to move them back to the right hand side, but I cannot find a way to change the button icons to those set up in my theme, Is this possible?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvMax.png

Here is a screenshot of chromium (Left) next to firefox (right) for reference as to what im trying to achieve. I want to make chromium's Minimise/Maximise/Close buttons more consistent with my Gnome 3 theme, such as they are on the Firefox window.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following..
Open a new tab in Chromium and type `chrome://settings/`

[image]

Go to **Appearance** and click in **"Use system title bar and borders"**

[image]

Cheers.